# WCF GridView paging and caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Is there a way to cache a user requested data depending upon the user/connection. My situation is that I display the data returned from the WCF in ASP.NET Gridview using paging. The gridview paging displays only 10 items at a time. Whenever the next page is clicked, the service is getting called again (which takes time). After each call the WCF connection is closed. Is there a way to fix this issue? I read upon WCF ASP.NET caching mechanism that caches functions call data and it expires after a certain time. My main thing, is per user/call caching like return 10 items at a time without calling the long running function again for each 10 sets of data. Is there a way to do?

Basically call the function the first time and get 100 items, and return it 10 at a time, without ever running the function again (which gets 100 items)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the ASP.NET Gridview always does a postback which result in function call everytime a user changes page. But I maybe proven wrong by someone.

That being said, this may not be the best solution for you. But you could avoid using ASP.NET Gridview in your scenario. When you run a WCF call and return 100 items, you keep them on client side as a JSON file stored in memory, then use jQuery or some other form of javascript to enable users to go through pages without making another function call.

**Edited**

This may prove useful to you to help you do paging on client-side without having multiple repeated call to the server
http://www.smallworkarounds.net/2009/02/jquery-aspnet-how-to-implement.html